# why does includeOptional not work the same as writing the code

Tags: apache, .htaccess, include, vhosts

I use apache 2.4 and I have some vhost files that have .htaccess disabled with                 AllowOverride None.

I thought the easiest way to include .htaccess files was to include them with this line

IncludeOptional /etc/httpd/.htaccess/domain.com/*

Now it does seem to include these files and they work however because I use itk to restrict the sites to specific users I believe setEnv wouldn't work in htaccess files. They also don't seem to work in this included files.

So if I put

SetEnv TESTFRED hoho2

inside a file in the .htaccess/domain.com folder it does not work.

If I put it directly under the includeOptional line in the vhost file it works fine.

Can anyone explain this behaviour and suggest a way I can include files and have apache run them as if they were inside the vhost file itself?

Answer (score -1):

apparently it's just claiming to include the file but not running it. Mystery solved.

Comment: Mistery solved but how? This answer should be useful for someone else different from you ;)